# Laravel Homestead - site cant be reached. Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Im getting started with Laravel Homestead and spend half a day working with tutorials and manuals.
The problem is that everything looks perfect - without any errors, but still I cant see laravel welcom page.

I've installed vagrant and virtual box.

at c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts added line like:

```
# 192.168.10.10 homestead.test
```

My directory tree looks like:

```
~/Server/.ssh
~/Server/Code
~/Server/Homestead
```

I made .ssh keys and using git bash:

```
cd Server
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
cd Homestead
bash init.sh
```

and configured homestead.yaml file:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/Server/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/Server/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Server/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/homestead/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Everything looks fine to me so far, is it?

Next in shell:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

successfully logged to laravel and changed directory to only one existing `code`, then:

```
laravel new homestead
```

Finished iwth message `Application ready! Build something amazing.`

Did also another one project with different names, but when I type in my chrome browser `homestead.test` or whatever I call my project -> This site can't be reached.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you made the vagrant box first then created a new app after ssh into the vagrant box. I usually take different steps.

1. Make sure vagrant is installed. https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
2. Make sure the laravel/homested box has been added to vagrant `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
3. Make sure homestead is installed on the home directory in a file named Homestead `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#first-steps
4. install homestead into your project `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`
5. use the make command to generate the vagrant and homestead.yaml files (for windows `vendor\\bin\\homestead make`) https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#per-project-installation
6. Configure the vagrant, homestead.yaml, and hosts file as you have done.
7. `vagrant up`

Comment: I did a box befor, just didnt mentioned about it.
Today I just feel like a stupid cause mistake was... damn...

```# 192.168.10.10 homestead.test``` <- here in hosts file.

I did that line like in whole file with # so thats a comment. That was a quick move so I wasnt focused there and was looking for mistake somwhere else.

Comment: Lol I missed it too. Glad you got it figured out. :)